# Eating something haram unintentionally, will my prayers be accepted?

Tags: salat, food

What if we ate something haram by mistake?

I ate some Korean brownie which the next day I found out has alcohol in it. but I didn't know because the label is all in Korean and I can't understand it. When my brother pointed out it has alcohol smell, I googled it and it's not halal. I'm so sad because it's Ramadan and I risked the acceptance of my prayers. Will my prayers be accepted because of this?

Comment: It is your intention that counts, as you never wanted to eat/drink alcohol you didn't do that on purpose, but this should be a lesson for the future. See also this post which has some relevance: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28804/subway-sandwich

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, you should ask forgiveness from Allah SWT in every slip, mishap and even when doing good. It is the habit of the prophets including Nabi SAW that they sought the forgiveness of Allah even after a good action. This is why we are recommended to say "Astaghfirallah" after Salah/Namaaz because even though we offered our prayer, we did not do so as Allah deserved, i.e. with full concentration/devotion.

A person who asks for forgiveness with sincerity is likened by Allah than another individual who doesn't sin at all *and* does *not* ask for forgiveness. So always ask for forgiveness, regardless of anything.

Secondly, there is certainly a difference of opinion from the scholars as to what the consequence is of eating haraam.

One example I heard from a scholar was the likeness of driving towards a ditch in a road but not knowing that the ditch is there. You're still going to fall in regardless if you know of it's existence. Haraam food is exceptionally bad and whether you know or not, there is still an effect on your Imaan.

If your case, your are still at fault. If the food is labelled in a different language and you do not understand then it's very, very important that you abstain from it as you are **unsure**. The fact that your brother saw the word Alcohol on the packet can only mean you did not undergo enough investigation.

...But this is where the question lies. How much investigation do you perform? A lot of my friends eat Vegetarian meals in takeaways which do not have Halal meat. The problem here is mix-contamination - The chef might use the same cutlery/pots/pans to cook the meat with the vegetarian food. But how are my friends to **truly** know if they are using separate tools for Veg and none Veg meals?

**Taqwa**. It's the Taqwa, the fear of Allah and our level of Imaan which we have that will help us abstain from something.

I won't comment on whether or not your prayers will be accepted as I don't know enough but the above will hopefully guide you in to doing the right thing in the future.

Comment: I know I'm still at fault bcs of my lack of knowledge and ignorance. May Allah forgive me and have mercy on me. My brother did not see the word alcohol, he just think it smells as if it contains alcohol. from that comment I googled and I found out it does. It's from my cousin and she's a muslim so I thought it is halal. Please pray so that Allah forgive me. syukron.

Comment: Just ask for forgiveness, be sincere and don't let it get *too* much to you..Be positive and fearful at the same time. Don't get too afraid or too slack. Keep a healthy balance of the fear of Allah and his mercy. Both are required.

Answer (score 1):

Alsalmo Alikom.

Yes, your prayer will be accepted inshaallah, since you have done this unintentionally, but take care next time.

Any thing you do will become haram if you do it on purpose . But if you do not know, or forget , or being forced , then you will not be punished.

The Prophet PBUH said " رفع عن امتى الخطأ و النسيان و ما استكرهوا عليه ". (See also in the wording of sunan ibn Majah [1](http://sunnah.com/urn/1321240) and [2](http://sunnah.com/urn/1321220))