# Is unintentionally eating haram food halal or haram?

Tags: halal-haram, food

What to do if someone ates haram food item unintentionally?

Is that haram or halal? Is it a sin? Will Allah forgive that person?

Comment: Somewhat related http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28804/subway-sandwich

Answer (score 4):

By considering following headees,

> Narrated ‘Umar bin Al-Khattab Radi Allahu Anhu: The Prophet Sallallahu Alaihi wasallam said, “”**The rewards (of deeds) are according to the intention, and everybody will get the reward for what he has intended**. So whoever emigrated for Allah’s and His Apostle’s sake, his emigration was for Allah and His Apostle Sallallahu Alaihi wasallam ; and whoever emigrated for worldly benefits, or to marry a woman, then his emigration was for the thing for what he emigrated for.””
>   Sahih Bukhari, Vol 7, Book 62, No. 8″

Doing something wrong **unintentionally** is not haram. But when you realizes that it was haram food then you should ask for forgiveness from Allah and check before eating from outside (especially from same hotel) next time .