# Is it haram to eat halal food that is touching haram food

Tags: halal-haram, food, meat

My family doesn't know I'm Muslim and I live away from home so this doesn't often.

But every now and again I will visit them and eat with them. Sometimes they'll cook a dish with a mixture of meat and vegetable.

Is it halal for me to eat the vegetable even thought it has touched the harm meat?

Comment: This seems relevant [If Subway staff mistakenly add meat to my sandwich is it halal to eat after ... ?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28804/if-subway-staff-mistakenly-add-meat-to-my-sandwich-is-it-halal-to-eat-after-rem)

Answer (score 1):

Haram food is unclean, or "Najis" for Muslims. It can clearly be understood that touching something unclean would make you unclean too.
So, if your food only touches the Haram food, you should remove that part of it before consuming. But as you stated that it is cooked with it, and cooking breaks down the ingredients in food, mixing them together, that means that those vegetables would have absorbed the juices of the haram meat and are now not considered halal anymore.
 الله أعلم.

Answer (score 0):

As I definitely know from طباطبائی یزدی، العروة الوثقی، المکتبة العلمیة الإسلامیة، ص۵۵ and امام خمینی، تحریر الوسیله، ص۱۰۷-۱۰۲ If haram food touches halal, like blood touches meat, you can clean it or cut that piece if you can't clean... But when two food cook together which one of them is not halal, they cant be eaten because they are already mixed. Cooking together, is different from touching.

You can suggest them to buy halal meat, not because they're Muslim, but because its more clean and healthy. Its proven by science and experience.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the question and answer site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model and not confound us with a typical internet forum I strongly recommend you to take the [tour] and check our [help]. Answers beginning with "As far as I know" are hardly what we look for we rather look for expert answers or answers where any claim is supported by evidences (see [answer]).