# I accidentally ate some non halal chicken, what should I do?

Tags: quran, fiqh, shiism

Heres the situation:

I went to a restaurant and ordered a "Vegetarian" dish. I have been to that restaurant many times and always have had only "Vegetarian" dishes. The dish I ordered also comes in meat form but I ordered the vegetarian version of it.

It was a curry and half way through eating it I saw a piece floating, on checking I found out it was chicken (non halal).

I did NOT actually eat/ingest the meat only the curry part but the meat was submerged in the curry. What should I do?

I feel horrible, I didn't mean to do it. It was an accident. Will I be forgiven? Are there any specific prayers I can perform?

Comment: Do you mean the chicken in your meal is non halal? Why do you consider it to be non halal?

Comment: @Envayo Yes the chicken in my meal was not halal (as in it was not butchered/cut/prepared according to the islamic law). The first time I went to the restaurant I asked them whether they sell halal meats. They said no, hence I decided to eat vegetarian. Most restaurants have a halal certificate as well (which they did not).

Comment: [This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/28804/13438) post seems relevant.

Comment: @Medi1Saif thanks. That helps. This has me really stressed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not responsible for unintentional mistakes.

> وليس عليكم جناح فيما أخطأتم به ولكن ما تعمدت قلوبكم وكان الله غفورا رحيما
>
> And there is no blame upon you for that in which you have erred but [only for] what your hearts intended. And ever is Allah Forgiving and Merciful.
>
> <sup>[Quran 33:5](https://quran.com/33/5)</sup>

Don't eat the rest of it and if possible vomit what you have eaten.  See https://islamweb.net/en/fatwa/84660/eating-haram-meat-by-mistake

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yeah I did not eat the rest of the it. I stopped eating once I figured out what had happened. Okay I will try to get it out. Thats one of the issues of living in a non muslim country. Again thanks for the answer.

Comment: "and if possible vomit what you have eaten" 
Are you serious? Why should he vomit out something haram he unintentionally consumed? Self-induced vomiting can cause serious harm to the digestive system and self-harm is haram. Even if he deliberately ate haram food he shouldn't vomit it out. Doing one haram act to compensate for another haram act is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

You have not sinned for the act that you didn't know of. As the above answer quotes [Quran 33:5](https://legacy.quran.com/33/5) , it says it all. There is also a Hadith to prove this:

> Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) once said **"The reward of deeds depends upon
> the intention and every person will get the reward according to what
> he has intended**." ([Sahih Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1))

This hadith itself clears many misconceptions that we mostly have.

Answer (score 0):

What should I do if I accidentally ate an illegal chicken?
If a person eats food without paying attention and after eating, he realizes that the food was forbidden, for example, the meat in the food was not halal, he is not responsible for it and his mistake was forgivable.

Ref: https://article.tebyan.net/275885/%D8%A7%DA%AF%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%86%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%87-%DA%AF%D9%88%D8%B4%D8%AA-%D8%AD%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A8%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%AF-