# I ate a gelatin product after being unsure if it contained it, what should Ido?

Tags: food

I have a chocolate marshmellow candy that i didnt know had gelatin as the ingredients are written in Spanish, i then asked a friend who knew Spanish if they could help me and tell me if it did, they told me that it didnt say gelatin but that it has an ingredient makes jello solidify, i googled what makes jello solidify and it said gelatin, but i ignored that and assumed it was something else as they told me it didnt say gelatin, i had a feeling that it still was gelatin but i ate it regardless because it didnt say it had it, after i ate it, my friend told me the name of the ingredient that “makes jello solid” i searched it up and it showed that it was gelatin, but just in spanish, now im stressing and i dont know what to do, i ate the marshmallow candy even with the feeling that it could still be gelatin, i felt this because many marshmallow products have gelatin, please someone help, what do i do now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I accidentally ate some non halal chicken, what should I do?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49413/i-accidentally-ate-some-non-halal-chicken-what-should-i-do)

Comment: I do not think so, I ate/ingested the candy, knowingly eating it but being unsure if it was gelatin, while still having a feeling that it might be.

Comment: It is a duplicate because you did not know that it was derived from pork. Hence it is a mistake and your heart did not intentionally want to disobey Allah.

Answer (score 0):

It is okay do not worry, as long as you didn't know it's fine and if you are not sure if the product has gelatin or not then it's best not to eat it.And also there is vegan gelatin and that is halal and a gelatin made from pig which is haram. You can use vegan gelatin in cooking its halal.
May Allah (swt) bless you inshallah and protect you and all of the ummah.
And if you have any other questions about will allah forgive you or not as long as you regret and truly apologize and promise that you won't do it again then you are forgiven never think that your sin is bigger than Allah that is actually a sin to think like that.