# Accidentally ate bacon crisps

Tags: halal-haram, food

I was having lunch and while on my way I took crips pack. While eating I felt tasteless thing and when I looked at wrapped it was "Smoky Bacon" favour.

I threw it away but what happens now. What do I do?

Comment: this raises other question such as is it a sin to eat "smoky Bacon" flavour crisp, since these are usually suitable for vegetarians, thus not really from haram sources at all, I guess it could be down to the intention. Everything is based on intention and you had no intention to have a taste of bacon.

Comment: This seems relevant https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/28804/13438

Comment: @Medi1Saif the only difference is instead of spitting out I sallowed it. Coz it almost passed the point where I can spit it out and I was in office and people were around me. So what happens in that case? Yes I did three the whole packet after knowing and repented. I was so sorry that I had headache later all day.

Comment: I'm sorry for what has happened. This post doesn't seem to meet the bar for a valid question and probably would attract recommendations as it is unclear what is being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bismi Allah Ar Rahman Ar Rahim.

In the name of God, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful.

Praise be to Almighty God,

and prayers and peace be upon the Messenger of Allah and his family and companions,

Having said that,

Peace be upon those who follow guidance

God Almighty said in Surat Al-Baqarah :

> ("He(Allah) has forbidden you carrion, and blood, and the flesh of swine, and what was dedicated to other than God. But if anyone is compelled, without desiring or exceeding, he commits no sin. God is Forgiving and Merciful")(Surat Al-Baqarah:173)

and said :

> (..."And know that God knows what is in yourselves (self-talk &  thought), so beware of Him. And know that God is Forgiving and Forbearing")(Surat Al-Baqarah:235)

if the sin was by mistake or by forcing then you are forgiven.

one of the scholars explained:
Allah is Oft-Forgiving. If you obey Allah in your Islam, avoid eating what is forbidden, and leave the followers of the Shaytaan, (obedience to the devil, and taking away his steps. Wrong, sin and disobedience), then Allah will forgive you, and Atone you for your sins, "merciful" to you if you obey him.

Wa Allaho A'alam,

and God knows everything,

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help]. Especially take a look at [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Allah forgives anything without the sin of comparing Allah with other. If you mistakenly done that remember that Allah is absolutely forgiver. So don't get worried and don't do that mistake again.

Comment: I think a supporting ayah would be [Qur'an 4:17](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=4&verse=17)